# Nativescript Vue Workers Slowing down the compilation a lot

Tags: performance, vue.js, compilation, nativescript, worker

After I added some workers to my project, the compilation process slowed down. Now I need to wait for a minute or two more after every save. It stacks on "File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...". Please help. Thanks!

Worker service:

```
    const workers = [];

    export class WorkerService {
      constructor() {}

      initDiscovered() {
    if (this.btScan) {
      return this.btScan;
    }

    const JsWorker = require("nativescript-worker-loader!./discovered.worker.js");
    this.btScan = new JsWorker();
    workers.push(this.btScan);

    return this.btScan;
  }

    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.dispose(() => {
        workers.forEach((w) => {
          w.terminate();
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: Did you try disabling HMR (`--no-hmr`)?

Comment: @Manoj Yes, it's  "tns run android --no-hmr". Also tried adding --bundle, but noticed no difference.